# Angular 2 Forms - Assign ngControl at sub-Component level

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In an Angular 2 Form, 
Trying to get data through ngSubmit.
I can assign both ngModel and ngControl properties within my form component without problem, however in the sub-component MyInput, I cannot assign ngControl without a "no provider error".
Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/LauhEz6vMaEmIg0hceoj?p=preview

```
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, MyInput],
template: ` <div>
                <form #hf="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(hf.value)">
                    <div>
                      In Form: <input type='text' [ngControl]="inform" [(ngModel)]="theValue" [required]="req" #spy >
                      <br>Classes: {{spy.className}}
                      <br>
                      <br>In Component: <my-input [props]='prop'></my-input>
                      <br>In Component: <my-input [props]='prop2'></my-input>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" [hidden] = "!editing">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" (click)="cancelClick()" [hidden] = "!editing">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" (click)="setEdit(true)" [hidden] = "editing">Edit</button>
                </form>
                Form Values {{data}}
           </div>
            `
```

Sub Component template:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-input',
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
template: ` 
            <input type='text'
              [(ngModel)]="props.Value"
```

Error if I add this

```
 [ngControl]="props.id"
```

Is there something I need to pass to the Sub Component from the form?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I was trying to do exactly the same stuff !

Comment: It seams to be a bug https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6374

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a problem that the prop is not available at the time of ngControl binding / execution... what if you provided a default controll in the component and then make a refference to the one from the `props` in `ngOnChange` which is executed at the time when the props are really available.

Comment: `[ngControl]="props?.id"` should assign `null` until `props` gets a value.

Comment: Is `elvis` operator supported by Angular 2 expression parser  ?

Comment: Yup, it is. Doesn't work in two-way shorthand syntax `[(xxx)]="yyy?.zzz"`. Might be obvious, but just to be sure ...

Comment: That's a really useful feature, didn't know about that thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Using this method, the parent form does not have the ability out of the box to determine its validity based on the validity of subcomponents.

As a workaround, you can try wrapping the sub-component in its own form element.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: ` 
      <form> <--------------
        <input type='text'
          [(ngModel)]="props.Value"
          [ngControl]="props.id"  />
      </form>
```

Not ideal, but it's the only way I could compose a form with sub-components without using dynamic forms https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html